# Cannot Horizontally Center Horizontal toggle sets

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

Im using jQuery Mobile and I have a horizontal toggle set.

I would like to center it in the page, **or** I would like to stretch it so that it takes up 100% of the width.
Either would be good for what I am doing.
I have tried a lot of different approaches but none have worked so far.
Using jQuery Mobile v1.0

```
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
        <input type="checkbox" name="monday" id="monday" class="custom"/>
        <label for="monday">Monday</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="tuesday" id="tuesday" class="custom" />
        <label for="tuesday">Tuesday</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="wednesday" id="wednesday" class="custom" />
        <label for="wednesday">Wednesday</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="thursday" id="thursday" class="custom" />
        <label for="thursday">Thursday</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="friday" id="friday" class="custom" />
        <label for="friday">Friday</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="saturday" id="saturday" class="custom" />
        <label for="saturday">Saturday</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="sunday" id="sunday" class="custom" />
        <label for="sunday">Sunday</label>
    </fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1):

I just had this same problem and I solved it by adding by putting the `fieldset` within a `div` which has `text-align: center` and then setting the `display` of the `fieldset` to `inline`.

E.g.

**HTML**

```
<div class="custom">
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
        <input type="checkbox" name="monday" id="monday" />
        <label for="monday">Monday</label>
        ...
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.custom {
    text-align: center;
}
.custom fieldset {
    display: inline;
}
```

Setting the `display` of the `fieldset` to `inline` may have some other effects, for example I noticed that the margins/padding changed slightly, but apart from that it did what I wanted.